# UpdateView along with updating another model fields?

Tags: python, html, django

```
class FootballUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Football
    fields = ['date', 'time', 'duration', 'category', 'place', 'game_status', 'event', 'score_team1', 'score_team2', 'team1', 'team2', 'game_level']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def post(self, request, pk):
        match = Football.objects.get(pk=pk)
        team1 = match.team1
        team2 = match.team2
        score_team1 = match.score_team1
        score_team2 = match.score_team2
        if score_team1 > score_team2:
            football_score = FootballScore.objects.filter(team=team1)[0]
            football_score.win = football_score.win + 1
            football_score.save()
            return HttpResponse('Score Successfully Updated! Team1 won!')
        else:
            football_score = FootballScore.objects.filter(team=team2)[0]
            football_score.win = football_score.win + 1
            football_score.save()
            return HttpResponse('Score Successfully Updated! Team2 won!')


------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Football(Match):
    score_team1 = models.IntegerField(default='-1')
    score_team2 = models.IntegerField(default='-1')
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team1_football', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='team2_football', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game_level = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES) # like semi-final, final etc
    # connect = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.game_level)


class FootballScore(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='teams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    win = models.IntegerField(default='0')
```

My Sport is Football with its usual fields, Now i am making Football score to update win field of Teams. As you can see, i have previously made UpdateView for Football model , Now i am making changes to it to add my new requirements of incrementing win field, Previously updateView was working fine, after adding "win" field, my win field in incrementing fine but update filed is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `my win field in incrementing fine but update filed is not working`.

Comment: I have a "win" field in "FootballScore" model, which i have added to update no. of wins by teams. Initially my UpdateView of "Football" was working fine, but when i have decided to change my "win" field depending on the updates of "Football" model by adding a function in "FootballUpdate" class of views.py, the "win" field is updating fine,but now the update of "Football" model itself is not working? @CoffeeBasedLifeform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matches (the `Football` objects) are not updated because your view does not save the updated version of the match given by the form. Usually, `UpdateView` would do that for you with the `post` method - by overriding that method, saving changes is your responsibility.

```
def post(self, request, pk):
    match = self.object = self.get_object() # Get the object that this view is working on and set 'self.object' as the ModelForm is going to look up that attribute
    form = self.get_form() # Get the actual ModelForm
    if not form.is_valid():
        # The user may have put in bad data, you wouldn't want to proceed then
        return super().form_invalid(form)
    form.save() # this updates the instance given to the ModelForm via 'self.object' with the data from the form
    team1 = match.team1
    team2 = match.team2
    score_team1 = match.score_team1
    score_team2 = match.score_team2
    if score_team1 > score_team2:
        football_score = FootballScore.objects.filter(team=team1)[0]
        football_score.win = football_score.win + 1
        football_score.save()
        return HttpResponse('Score Successfully Updated! Team1 won!')
    else:
        football_score = FootballScore.objects.filter(team=team2)[0]
        football_score.win = football_score.win + 1
        football_score.save()
        return HttpResponse('Score Successfully Updated! Team2 won!')
```